# How to prevent subprocess.call from printing return code?

Tags: python, subprocess

How do I stop that zero from dangling off the end of this print statement when using subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)?

```
print("The top five memory consumers on the system are:")
print(subprocess.call('ps -eo pid,ppid,cmd,%mem,%cpu --sort=-%mem | head -n 6', shell=True))
```

output:

```
The top five memory consumers on the system are:
  PID  PPID CMD                         %MEM %CPU
  807     1 /usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sb  3.1  0.0
  615   555 /sbin/dhclient -d -q -sf /u  3.0  0.0
 1500   917 python                       1.7  0.0
 9921   917 python ./dkap_sysinfo.py     1.7  0.0
  556     1 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n        1.3  0.0
0
```

^ Problem child

Comment: Um - remove the print.  You're the one doing it.  So, don't.  Replace `print(subprocess.call(...))` with `subprocess.call(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subprocess.check_output()` instead of `subprocess.call()`:

```
import subprocess

print("The top five memory consumers on the system are:")

cmd = "ps -eo pid,ppid,cmd,%mem,%cpu --sort=-%mem | head -n 6"
result = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).decode()

lines = result.split("\n")
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

Also note that the result of `check_output()` is a bytes-like object, so you must call `.decode()` on it if you want to work with it as a string.